# I am a little bit confused by the super().__init__()

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my code:

```
class StrKeyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __missing__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, str):
            raise KeyError(key)
        return self[str(key)]

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.keys() or str(key) in self.keys()

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = StrKeyDict([('2', 'two'), ('4', "four")])
```

I want to inherit the build-in dict, so I use super(). But when I use `StrKeyDict([('2', 'two'), ('4', "four")])` to initialize it, error comes like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nick/PyProjects/Fluent-Python/3-6.py", line 25, in <module>
    d = StrKeyDict([('2', 'two'), ('4', "four")])
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

However, if I delete `__init__()` the whole class will work just fine. So my question is:

1. Is `super().__init__()` a must in every class?
2. If I want to keep `super().__init__()`, how would I modify?

Comment: It doesn't really have to do with `super()`. You defined `__init__(self)` taking only one argument (`self`), but you passed two arguments (the instance implicitly as `self`, and the list `[('2', 'two'), ('4', "four")]`).

Comment: (But of course you would then also have to pass the second argument to `super.__init__`, otherwise the functionality to initialize your dictionary with a value would get lost.)

Comment: You are using `StrKeyDict`'s `__init__()` when calling `StrKeyDict()` not `dict`'s;                 super is basically the extended class of the current class *not really but close enough* that means this `super.__init__()` is equivalent to this `dict.__init__()`

Comment: Your error is because you are constructing your object with an argument, but your `__init__` method doesn't take any arguments (except for the required `self`). If you take an argument and pass it to the superclass's init, like `def __init__(self, arg): super().__init__(arg)` then it should work.

Answer (score 2):

By doing this `class StrKeyDict(dict):` you inherit dict, there is no need for init unless you want to initialize something when the class is created.

Answer (score 1):

The error is raised because your call to create a `StrKeyDict` passed in the array and you did not allow for it in `__init__`'s  parameters.  it should have been:

```
def __init__(self,  my_list):
   ...
```

etc

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it. But I want it to behave the exact same way as the buildin dict when it comes to initialization. So I just delete __init__().

Comment: that will work or you could pass my_list to the super init if needed and if its a valid parameter.  Looks like you have a solution for your current issue though.

Answer (score 1):

> Is `super().__init__()` a must in every class?

No, you only need it when you want to run the inherited `__init__` **and** do something extra, like only allowing certain parameters, or further mutating `self` afterwards.

In this case, where `StrKeyDict.__init__()` doesn't do anything extra, you should remove it and let `StrKeyDict` inherit `dict.__init__()`.

> If I want to keep `super().__init__()`, how would I modify?

You would need `StrKeyDict.__init__()` to take arguments and pass them to `super().__init__()`.

If you want to be permissive/lazy, you can allow anything:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or if you want to be restrictive, match the signature of `dict.__init__()`:

```
def __init__(self, mapping_or_iterable, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(mapping_or_iterable, **kwargs)
```

P.S. I've let out some nuances here, but this should be enough to get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

- Whenever you create a new instance of a class init method is called. It's like a constructer. Since your init method need not require any argument but you are passing a list, that's why you are getting this error.
  When you call the super method init method of inherited class is being called.

Here is rectified code:

```
class StrKeyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self,lst):
        super().__init__(lst)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, str):
            raise KeyError(key)
        return self[str(key)]

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.keys() or str(key) in self.keys()

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = StrKeyDict([('2', 'two'), ('4', "four")])
```